# How can I create a char array variable that changes its value every time I run the code?

Tags: c

I am using char array variable which is declared like this :

```
char our_thread[8]="thread1";
```

I am using it into a function which creates threads :

```
kthread_create(thread_fn,NULL,our_thread);
```

The thread will be named "thread1" in the list of processes .

I want to change thread1 char array variable into a dynamic variable in order that every time the thread is created will have another name instead of "thread1".

Thank you.

Comment: So search about how to generate random numbers and how to concatenate numbers into strings. This seems too vague/broad for SO as currently written.

Comment: You could base the name on the current time in seconds the first time it it runs the thread, and increment the number after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit broad, but anyway maybe this helps:

```
char our_thread[20];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
  sprintf(out_thread, "thread%d", rand() % 100);
  printf("thread name %s\n", our_thread);
}
```

You should be able to figure out the rest.

Read the documentation of [`rand`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) and [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/).